# find difference between two text files with one item per line

Tags: bash, file, scripting, sed, awk

I have two files:

file 1

```
dsf
sdfsd
dsfsdf
```

file 2

```
ljljlj 
lkklk 
dsf
sdfsd
dsfsdf
```

I want to display what is in file 2 but not in file 1, so file 3 should look like

```
ljljlj 
lkklk
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can try

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

or

```
grep -v -F -x -f file1 file2
```

Comment: This won't work. Try adding `dsfblah` to file2.

Comment: You can fix it with `grep -F -x`

Comment: I think your suggestion was worth editing the answer @tripleee

Comment: Note that the ordering of the files matters.  I'm trying to detect a new addition to a file.  I have to write `grep -v -f oldfile newfile` or else it will output nothing.

Comment: Imagine me: git add file1. git commit. cat file2 > file1. git diff. 

Comment: krico@ Can you add explanation for parameter that you pass?

Answer (score 170):

```
grep -Fxvf file1 file2
```

What the flags mean:

```
-F, --fixed-strings
              Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.    
-x, --line-regexp
              Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.
-v, --invert-match
              Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
-f FILE, --file=FILE
              Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
```

Comment: Option `-n` could be added to number the differing lines

Comment: Any way to highlight the non-matching part of each line?

Comment: With this you can find the first difference only and print its line number too: `grep -m 1 -Fnxvf file1 file2`

Comment: Very inefficient on large files.

Answer (score 48):

You can use the `comm` command to compare two sorted files

```
comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: FYI, it is actually `comm -1 -3 file1 file2`. The two flags `1` and `3` are merged into one.

Comment: comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)   will output only those in file1 and not in file2 -- the best part of this is any arrangement in file2 works where diff will fail; say file1 has 1,2,3,4,5 and file2 has 1,2,4,5 you get 3 diff will get it wrong

Answer (score 14):

I successfully used

```
diff "${file1}" "${file2}" | grep "<" | sed 's/^<//g' > "${diff_file}"
```

Outputting the difference to a file.

Comment: What better way to find differences than to use a diff tool haha. Is there higher overhead with using this versus grep?

Answer (score 9):

if you are expecting them in a certain order, you can just use `diff`

`diff file1 file2 | grep ">"`

Answer (score 7):

```
join -v 2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Answer (score 4):

A tried a slight variation on [Luca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032370/luca-borrione)'s answer and it worked for me.

```
diff file1 file2 | grep ">" | sed 's/^> //g' > diff_file
```

Note that the searched pattern in sed is a `>` followed by a space.

Answer (score 3):

```
file1 
m1
m2
m3

file2 
m2
m4
m5

>awk 'NR == FNR {file1[$0]++; next} !($0 in file1)' file1 file2
m4
m5

>awk 'NR == FNR {file1[$0]++; next} ($0 in file1)' file1 file2
m2

> What's awk command to get 'm1 and m3' ??  as in file1 and not in file2? 
m1
m3
```

Answer (score 1):

an awk answer:

`awk 'NR == FNR {file1[$0]++; next} !($0 in file1)' file1 file2`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use loops You can try like this: (diff and cmp are much more efficient. )

```
while read line
do
    flag = 0
    while read line2
    do
       if ( "$line" = "$line2" )
        then
            flag = 1
        fi
     done < file1 
     if ( flag -eq 0 )
     then
         echo $line > file3
     fi
done < file2
```

Note: The program is only to provide a basic insight into what can be done if u dont want to use system calls such as diff n comm..

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's#[^^]#[&]#g;s#\^#\\^#g;s#^#/^#;s#$#$/d#' file1 | sed -f- file2
```

**How it works:**

The first `sed` produces an output like this:

```
/^[d][s][f]$/d
/^[s][d][f][s][d]$/d
/^[d][s][f][s][d][f]$/d
```

Then it is used as a `sed` script by the second `sed`.