# How to compare two different files line by line and write the difference in third file?

Tags: python, file

I would like to compare two text files which have three columns each. One file has 999 rows and another has 757 rows. I want the different 242 rows to be stored in a different file. I created the first file (999 rows) using a random network generator (999 rows are edges with third column being weight between first, second columns - source, destination nodes).

**File Format - Files 1, 2**

```
1 3 1
16 36 1
```

I have tried

[Compare two files line by line and generate the difference in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544709/compare-two-files-line-by-line-and-generate-the-difference-in-another-file)
and
[find difference between two text files with one item per line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078933/find-difference-between-two-text-files-with-one-item-per-line) and http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/124932/610058#post610058

Neither worked for me.

I think it is a problem of string comparison. I would like to compare the numbers in first column and second column. If they both are different, I want to write it to third file.

Any help will be much appreciated!

**Update**

I am posting the following code that I tried after @MK posted his comment.

```
f = open("results.txt","w")

for line in file("100rwsnMore.txt"):
    rwsncount += 1
    line = line.split()
    src = line[0]
    dest = line[1]
    for row in file("100rwsnDeleted.txt"):
        row = row.split()
        s = row[0]
        d = row[1]
        if(s != src and d != dest):
             f.write(str(s))
             f.write(' ')
             f.write(str(d))
             f.write('\n')

f.close()
```

Comment: Not a real question.  What exactly didn't work and what exactly did you try?

Comment: What's wrong with good old [`diff(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff)?

Comment: this has 999 lines! I need to write the difference to another file. It has written 1752 lines to a new file.

Comment: "sort filea fileb | uniq" would work better.

Comment: Have you tried Python's [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best general-purpose option if you're on a *nix system is just to use:

```
sort filea fileb | uniq -u
```

But if you need to use Python:

Your code reopens the inner file in every iteration of the outer file.  Open it outside the loop.

Using a nested loop is less efficient than looping over the first storing the found values, and then comparing the second to those values.

```
def build_set(filename):
    # A set stores a collection of unique items.  Both adding items and searching for them
    # are quick, so it's perfect for this application.
    found = set()

    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            # [:2] gives us the first two elements of the list.
            # Tuples, unlike lists, cannot be changed, which is a requirement for anything
            # being stored in a set.
            found.add(tuple(sorted(line.split()[:2])))

    return found

set_more = build_set('100rwsnMore.txt')
set_del = build_set('100rwsnDeleted.txt')

with open('results.txt', 'w') as out_file:
   # Using with to open files ensures that they are properly closed, even if the code
   # raises an exception.

   for res in (set_more - set_del):
      # The - computes the elements in set_more not in set_del.

      out_file.write(" ".join(res) + "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you the reply Zack. not every line from 100rwsnDeleted file is deleted. The line count is 350 as supposed to 242. I created the 100rwsnDeleted file from 100rwsnMore file initially by comparing 'More' file with another file (with 242 rows). I just wanted to make it clear that all rows in 100rwsnDeleted file are derived from 100rwsnMore file.

Comment: @bhanu I just made a fix which should cause it to operate the way you expect, give it a shot.

Comment: I tried it. It added too many lines. The count is 942. I will try uploading the text files.

Comment: Ah, I think I see, I changed the operator in the set comparison, give it a shot.

Comment: Nothing changed. I must mention that if the larger file has 11 86 1 as a row and second file has 86 11 1 as a row, it must be considered as common edge and should not figure in the results.txt file.

Comment: In the sense that, the edge is bidirectional and not unidirectional (graphs). These rows are essentially edges in a network represented as a graph. *If it was not clear to you already*.

Comment: Yes, that would be important to mention.  I added a sorting to the numbers so they will compare correctly irrespective of order.

Comment: Thank you Zack, sorry for not explicitly mentioning it before. You've been of great help! It worked!! Thank you :)