# How to output any lines from a file, excluding those found in another file?

Tags: bash

I need to output all lines in `file1.txt`, except those that are found in `file2.txt`, by matching the entirely lines.

E.g., `file1.txt`:

```
Cats eat fish.
Mice eat cheese.
Eagles can fly.
Mountains are tall.
```

E.g., `file2.txt`:

```
Cats eat fish.
Birds can fly.
Trees are tall.
```

E.g., output:

```
Mice eat cheese.
Eagles fly.
Mountains are tall.
```

I have used the following command:

```
grep -v -x -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

This appears to work, however, when the files are of certain lengths, it often reports `grep: memory exhausted`, so I need an alternative that will not create this memory problem.

- The order of the lines is important, so they should not be sorted.
- Any tool typically found within a default Linux install will be acceptable.

How can I output the lines of `file1.txt`, except those found in `file2.txt`, without encountering a memory problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `grep -vxf f2 f1` instead? (First f2, then f1). It works fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
grep -Fxvf file2.txt file1.txt
```

References: [find difference between two text files with one item per line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078933/find-difference-between-two-text-files-with-one-item-per-line)

Comment: In my tests so far, it seems to work. How does the addition of `-F` stop the memory problem?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
rm -f out.txt && while read -r line; do echo "checking if line $line exists in file2.txt"; if `grep -Fxq "$line" file2.txt`; then echo "$line exists in other for"; else echo "$line" >> out.txt; fi; done < file.txt
```

Explaination:

this deletes the output file (in case of continuous use...), then it checks line by line if one exists in the other.

As a bash file it's clearer:

```
rm out.txt
while read -r line
do
    echo "checking if line $line exists in file2.txt"
    if `grep -Fxq "$line" file2.txt`
    then
        echo "$line exists in other file"
    else 
        echo "$line" >> out.txt
    fi
done < file.txt
```

And the obvious generalization:

```
while read -r line
do
    echo "checking if line $line exists in $2"
    if `grep -Fxq "$line" $2`
    then
        echo "$line exists in $2"
    else 
        echo "$line" >> $3
    fi
done < $1
```

Where the first and second arguments would be the files and the outut file would be the third argument