# unix utility to compare lists and perform a set operation

Tags: shell, sorting, unix, set, utility

I believe what I'm asking for is a sort of set operation. I need help trying to create a list of the following:

List1 contains:

```
1
2
3
A
B
C
```

List2 contains:

```
1
2
3
4
5
A
B
C
D
E
```

(I need this) - The Final list I need would be (4) items:

```
4
5
D
E
```

So obviously List2 contains more elements than List1.
Final list which I needs are the elements in List2 that are NOT in List1.

Which linux utility can I use to accomplish this? I have looked at `sort`, `comm` but i'm unsure how to do this correctly. Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you make an attempt, there are plenty of questions around for similar logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find difference between two text files with one item per line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078933/find-difference-between-two-text-files-with-one-item-per-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` with a straight forward logic.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]; next}!($0 in a)' file1 file2
4
5
D
E
```

Using `GNU comm` utility, where according to the `man comm` page,

```
comm -3 file1 file2
      Print lines in file1 not in file2, and vice versa.
```

Using it for your example

```
comm -3 file2 file1
4
5
D
E
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple `grep` command inverting the match with `-v` and reading the search terms from list1 with `-f`, e.g. `grep -v -f list1 list2`. Example use:

```
$ grep -v -f list1 list2
4
5
D
E
```

Linux provides a number of different ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$ diff list1.txt list2.txt | egrep '>|<' | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -u
4
5
D
E
```

i hope help you